# internet connection interrupted and Limited

Tags: wireless-networking

My internet connection keeps getting interrupted intermittently.  I'm running windows 8 on an Acer Laptop.  I have checked for any connectivity problems and the driver devices and all are running properly. I disconnected and reconnected the modem and wifi. When it gets interrupted the wifi connection indicates "limited."
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

First off- you're using wireless. This is the most likely cause of the intermittent connection, but we have no way of knowing until you take it out of the equation.

So you should find an Ethernet cable, disable the wireless card (in your laptop) for a while, and see how your browsing experience compares when you are plugged in directly.

After a few hours of bypassing the wireless connection, post back and let us know how it went. My guess is it will run absolutely perfectly in this scenario.

Then, after *confirming* whether wireless is indeed the problem- you can stat looking into resolving that issue. If it's not the wireless, that's great too, let us know.

You should be able to at least identify this issue today- although it may take a little longer to actually fix if your wireless is flaky.

Comment: Alternatively, another laptop using the same wireless network painlessly — or the same computer having the same problem with another wireless network — would indicate it's the laptop in itself that causes the problem. What to do then ?

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to see if anyone is using a microwave oven nearby. I've known of leaky ovens that can cause intermittent problems, and sometimes you may just have to move around to find a better location, or re-orientate your access point aerial.

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-networking/wi-fi-connection-repeatedly-goeslimited-on-windows/eec795c0-9a33-4060-9200-c9d865ae31e3) suggests a few solutions, among which:

- Installing the Acer wifi drivers (remove them, install from Acer, restart the device);
- Unchecking "allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" in the network card power settings;
- Changing your network setup.

Could well be the driver problem if you think it's Acer-specific, or the power management one if (as in my case) all is back to normal after a little while if left untouched, or faster if woken up.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was an issue I've had before relative to my school's wifi and my laptop. 2 solutions I know of. Speaking of, make sure you are using Google Chrome! ;)

Solutions 1 and 3 will require you to be on the current wifi! And solutions 1 & 3 require you to go here first: Right-click the wifi bar in system tray>Open Network and Sharing Center>Public Network.

1. **Change from Public network to Home network of Business network.**

   Sometimes Public network will restrict some internet access. Go to Public Network, you can change it there. But you possibly may not have the choice.
2. **Update network drivers.**

    Win (Windows Start Key)+W> search "driver">"Device Manager">"Network Adapters">Right Click "Broadcam 802.11n Netork Adapter">"Update Driver Software...">"Browse my computer for driver software">"Let me pick from a list of drivers on my computer">Click once to highlight "Broadcam 802.11n Netork Adapter (Broadcam)">Next

   **This was personally my favorite solution since it was the one that fixed mine.**
3. **Turn off Auto-Disable Power Saver**

   Go to "Wi-Fi (Insert name here)">"Properties">"Configure">Power Management">Uncheck "Allow this computer to turn off this device to save power"

Any of these solutions should work. Now it may seem like a lot of information to take in, but it took me longer to type this.

Here are all the image links: http://pastebin.com/qkeEDg4E